# How to set the margin in LaTeX?

Tags: margins

I want to set the margin like this:

```
Paper size:  A4 or US Letter

US Letter first page    Top 72 Left 54 Right 54 Bottom 54 pt
US Letter other pages   Top 54 Left 54 Right 54 Bottom 54 pt

Font embedding: Fonts that are not embedded may be rendered incorrectly

Font subsetting: Subsetting embedded fonts reduces the file size

Type 3 fonts are rasterized fonts, which may impair the on-screen
readability of the document

Oriental fonts require oriental language
```

How to realize it in the LaTeX form?
Thank you so much!

Comment: Look here for questions with the geometry package.

Comment: @Dr.ManuelKuehner, Look where?

Comment: @Dr.ManuelKuehner, can you write an answer?

Comment: Here at stackexchange. I go to bed now. Your question is easily solved with the geometry package. Have a look in the manual or use the search function here.

Comment: Do you have text flowing naturally from "US letter first page" to "US letter second page? Or is there a clean break between the two (like in the case with a first-page title and a second page article content)? Also, what about headers and footers in your document? Are they included in/excluded from the measurements you give?

Comment: @Werner, I am a newbie for latex. I use IEEE bare_conf.tex. I do not know how to answer your question. I just want to realize the requirement. Please post an answer here, I will vote! Thanks!

Comment: @Werner, I am writing a 4-pages conference paper.

Comment: @Shawn: Do you know that [`bare_conf.tex`](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/IEEEtran/bare_conf.tex) includes the following as a comment in the document preamble: "Do not adjust lengths that control margins, column widths, etc. ... Unless specifically asked to do so by the journal or conference you plan
% to submit to, of course." Is this the case?

Comment: @Werner, but the submitting system requires the format I post here. It is not my will. otherwise the system will not accept my paper. I am very newbie for latex. I really do not know how to achieve that. When I start writing my paper, I just use bare_conf.tex as the template.

Comment: @Werner, can you post an answer here? I will vote!

Comment: First rule of LaTeX - there are so many things you can do, and so many ways of doing them, that it's always important to include as much information as you can in the question. It's true, we ask for *minimal* working examples, because we don't want to have to page through stuff that isn't relevant and, no, we don't need to know what you had for breakfast, or what your mother's maiden name is - but, if a piece of information seems in any way related to the question - put it in, my friend, put it in! :)

Comment: @Au101, that is all I can say, since I am really a newbie.

Comment: That's fine :) The point I was making is you needed to put it in the question to begin with, which would have saved this comment thread and would allow everyone viewing this question to see all the information they need to help you right away. I recommend that you edit your question now, but I was mainly trying to give you some helpful advice for next time. I could see that you are also new to the site, which can be confusing, so I was giving you the most important piece of advice I could - good things come to those who put the information in the question :)

Comment: (By it, I mean the fact you're using bare_conf.tex, the fact that the submission system requires the format, and the fact that you're writing a 4-page conference paper. Put it in, my friend, put it in! :) )

Comment: @Au101, I edit the question according to the submitting system.

Comment: @Au101, that is all information I have now

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is one option, using [`geometry`](http://ctan.org/pkg/geometry). Add the following to your preamble:

```
\usepackage{geometry}
\geometry{
  paper=a4paper,
  margin=54pt,
  includeheadfoot
}
```

This sets *all* margins (top, bottom, left *and* right) to be 54pt on an A4 page (use `paper=letterpaper` if you're using US Letter size). Additionally, the margins are set to include the header and footer as part of the specification. This, however, doesn't meet the requirements for the first page, which has to have a top margin of 72pt (18pt more than the other pages). For this, I'd insert an appropriate vertical adjustment on the first page by also adding

```
\renewcommand{\IEEEtitletopspaceextra}{\dimexpr-\headheight-\headsep+18pt\relax}
```

somewhere within your document preamble.

Comment: it is not 74pt. It is 72, there is no 74 in my requirement. Please update your answer.

Comment: I add this "\renewcommand{\IEEEtitletopspaceextra}{\dimexpr-\headheight-\headsep+18pt\relax}"  below " \begin{document} ".   There is error pop up.

Comment: The error is :! LaTeX Error: \IEEEtitletopspaceextra undefined.
See the LaTeX manual or LaTeX Companion for explanation.
Type H <return> for immediate help.

Comment: How to fix the problem? Please update your answer!

Comment: @Shawn: Please [update your distribution](http://goo.gl/CqWB1) and try again.

Comment: I do not understand the link you send to me

Comment: I am windows 7. Can you teach me a easier way?

Comment: @Shawn: Then you're either using MiKTeX or TeX Live. Which is it?

Comment: I use MikTex to edit my .tex file

Comment: @Shawn: No, MiKTeX is your *distribution*. You edit your `.tex` files with something else (like TeXnicCenter). You can probably follow [these directions](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/55473/5764).

Comment: I update MikTex ,but there is still the same error there. I do not understand what you specifically want me to do ?

Comment: You mention you use `bare_conf.tex`. When I use [`bare_conf.tex`](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/IEEEtran/bare_conf.tex) (notice the link) and compile it with my suggestion, I don't get any errors. I have an up-to-date system, since the version for [`IEEEtran.cls`](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/IEEEtran/IEEEtran.cls) I have is 2015/08/26 V1.8b. What do you have? To see, add `\listfiles` to your preamble, as suggested in [Which package version am I using?](http://goo.gl/sBfU5X)

Comment: @Shawn please try not to badger users like this, they're people with lives (mostly, one of us is a duck, actually) who use their free time to help you for nothing. It's nice to help people, and users get some meaningless rep points out of it - but they cannot change these up at the bank and go out and buy a sandwich. I understand that you are eager - perhaps desperate - to get a solution, but don't pester people. This isn't a support team you're paying a subscription to, from whom you can expect an answer. It's a Q&A site. Manners, my friend, respect, patience, gratitude.